# What is wrong with my resetSize() function? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, css, get, document

I simply made a `div` and gave it height and width. Then I made a function called `resetSize()` from which I want to change the height and width of any element, but something's wrong! Here's my source code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Get Value</title>
        <style>
            #demo{
                height:50px;
                width:50px;
                background:cyan;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="demo"></div>
    </body>

    <script>
        function resetSize(elementId, height, width){
            var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
            el.style.height = height;
            el.style.width = width;
        }
        resetSize('demo', 500, 500);
    </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add units, like `px`.

```
function resetSize(elementId, height, width){
    var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
    el.style.height = height + "px";
    el.style.width = width + "px";
}
```

---

The above way is hardcoded to `"px"`. You could pass the unit instead.

```
function resetSize(elementId, height, width, unit){
    var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
    el.style.height = height + (unit || "px");
    el.style.width = width + (unit || "px");
}

resetSize('demo', 500, 500, "px");
```

---

Or just include it directly in the value, and use the original function.

```
resetSize('demo', "500px", "500px");
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing you missing is `px` - the unit

```
function resetSize(elementId, height, width) {
    var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
    el.style.height = height + 'px';
    el.style.width = width + 'px';
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6wwQz/)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the `px`. See http://jsfiddle.net/X5B4r/ for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Your height & width need to be set as strings with the 'px' unit notation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Get Value</title>
        <style>
            #demo{
                height:50px;
                width:50px;
                background:cyan;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="demo"></div>
    </body>

    <script>
        function resetSize(elementId, height, width) {
            var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
            el.style.height = height;
            el.style.width = width;
        }
        resetSize('demo', '500px', '500px');
    </script>

</html>
```